# load the kml file into google earth using vb.net

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

please Can anyone help for load the kml file into google earth using vb.net
and i have another question how to parse the xml file into kml file.
please answer my question as soon as possible.

with regards

Firoz

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the Google Earth desktop client? If you can execute commands (using Process.Start()? I'm not a vb.net developer...), starting Google Earth with the name of the KML file will work:

```
googleearth.exe "filename.kml"
```

If you're talking about running the Google Earth plugin inside a .net application (since your question is tagged with google-earth-plugin), you use the javascript interface from .net code just like you do all commands to the plugin. See this article for an overview of the different methods of loading KML via the Javascript API: [An Overview of Using KML in the Earth API](https://developers.google.com/earth/articles/earthapikml).

You'll have to be more specific about your question about parsing xml into a KML file. KML *is* KML (though obviously not all KML is XML. You'll have to talk about the format of the XML (perhaps in a different question) to get help with that problem.

In the meantime the [KML reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference) gives lots of details on the KML spec. There are also many KML converters out there...try searching around and seeing if any will help you with whatever format of XML you have.